# Call R notebooks on Databricks from second R notebook

Tags: sparkr, databricks, spark-submit

I try to call a R notebook on Databricks while passing parameters using `spark-submit`.

My approach looks like this:

```
com <- "spark-submit foo.R p1 & spark-submit foo.R p2"
system(com)
```

This should call the script `foo.R`and hand over the parameter `p1`.

This returns:

```
 sh: 1: spark-submit: not found
 sh: 1: spark-submit: not found
```

I would expect that this submits the two jobs to the Spark cluster. Any help what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you attempted to run these commands in a R notebook. The standard way to call other notebooks from a Databricks notebook is [dbutils.notebook.run](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#run-usage). Currently it only works in Python and Scala.

You can work around it by adding a Python cell to your R notebook:

```
%python
dbutils.notebook.run("foo.R", 60, {"argument": "p1"})
dbutils.notebook.run("foo.R", 60, {"argument": "p2"})
```

In case you generate notebook parameters p1 and p2 in R, you can use a temporary view to pass them to the Python cell.

Comment: How can the notebook foo.R reference/process the arguments?