# Call notebook using R in Databricks

Tags: r, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a R notebook in Databricks, that I want to call inside an other R notebook.

I know that to call the notebook_a, one should do :

```
%run /path/notebook_a
```

But I want to do it inside an R script. For example :

```
if(condition){ %run /path/notebook_a }
```

Of course this code does not work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [dbutils.notebooks.run](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html) for calling another notebook, but there is a difference between it and `%run`:

- `dbutils.notebooks.run` executes another notebook as a separate job, so no definitions, etc. is pulled into the context of the current notebook - you can communicated data via temp views, etc.
- `%run` execute another notebook and pulls all definitions and sides effects into the context of the current notebook.

I'm not sure if `dbutils.notebooks.run` will help in your case.

P.S. I personally would recommend to use `%run` with notebooks that only define functions, not doing any calculations, etc. - in this case, even if you have `%run` this doesn't cause any side effect on your current context.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want the notebook that is called to make calculations, create variables, and pull them into the calling notebook ?

Comment: what about wrapping code as R library, and calling it?

Comment: This answer has a workaround that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898772/call-r-notebooks-on-databricks-from-second-r-notebook

Comment: @AlexOtt I probably could but it seems a bit tidous for something as simple as calling another script don't you think ?